# How to get a 'JBoss service' with CDI in JMX with AS6?

Tags: java, service, jmx, cdi, jboss6.x

I'm currently migrating a JBoss service class from AS5.1 to AS6 (not going to AS7 for a variety of reasons).

For AS5.1, the service implements a {serviceName}MBean and has a jboss-service.xml with attribute values. It's packaged in a jboss-sar, which is packaged in an EAR to be deployed. When deployed, the service fields are populated with the values from jboss-service.xml, and the service is automatically registered into JMX.

I would like to achieve the same thing using AS6, but would like the service to support CDI - so I'd like its new @Inject injection points to be satisfied. I need these to be satisfied in the object registered with JMX, so that methods called via JMX can reference injected fields, but I'm struggling to achieve this.

I've had to package the service in a jar, instead of a jboss-sar, for classloader reasons, but let's say it's otherwise unchanged. When deployed to AS6, all works as before - service goes into JMX, values from XML propagate to the object. However, the instance created does not have its CDI injection points satisfied, and neither does the object registered in JMX.

If I annotate the service class with @Startup and @javax.ejb.Singleton, but keep its interface and the jboss-service.xml, the object registered into JMX still does not have its CDI injection points satisfied. However if I programmattically deregister that bean, and re-register the instance in a @PostConstruct method, then the bean in JMX DOES have its injection points satisfied. However that bean no longer has the values specified in the jboss-service.xml.

So how can I get the best of both worlds? CDI and the usual JBoss service behaviour? What is the correct way to implement a JBoss service with CDI? I've been unable to find documentation on this. Hope someone can help.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: In J2EE terms, what kind of thing is a JBoss service? Is it an EJB, a servlet, a JAX-WS handler, or what? Or (as i suspect) is it not any kind of J2EE object? If it isn't, it's not clear that CDI can be applied to it. You mention trying making it a @Singleton, but it seems that what that does is makes the class play two disjoint roles - it is instantiated as an EJB, and separately instantiated as a service. The EJB copy gets injected, the service copy doesn't; the service copy gets the jboss-service.xml configuration, the EJB copy doesn't.

Comment: Apologies for being the bearer of bad news! Could you split the service into two parts - an EJB, and a sort of lightweight service adaptor which is loaded and configured via a jboss-service.xml, and does one explicit JNDI lookup to get hold of the bean?

Comment: I think you're spot on with EJB/service behaviour in your first comment, Tom. I was thinking that it would still be treated as a bog-standard CDI managed bean - so would be able to have CDI. Appears not to be the case. Will definitely look into the 2-part service implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, it seems Tom's right - there's no 'nice' way of created a CDIed, JMX bean in one go, you either have to put your JMX bean in CDI, as is suggested above, or put you CDIed bean into JMX. We tried the former, but it appears the BeanManager isn't bound to JNDI at the point the service starts up.

So instead we went with CDI bean -> JMX. We're creating the services as Singleton EJBs, so their injection points are satisfied, and they then get registered/unregistered to JMX in their PostConstruct/PreDestroy methods, using German Escobar's excellent CDI portable extension (germanescobar.net/2010/01/cdi-portable-extension-jmx.html, community.jboss.org/thread/148750 is also helpful).

May try to use ApplicationScoped beans and get them to start by observing a ContainerInitialized(?) event, however, as we don't need all the features of an EJB. Haven't tried that yet, mind...

Answer (score 1):

As a worst-case fallback, you should be able to use the [CDI extension API](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html/extend.html) to get your service to be injected. I don't think you would need to write a fully-fledged extension, but if you have an initialisation hook in the service object, you can do this (lifted with minor editing from the docs, not compiled or tested):

```
public static <T> void inject(T object) {
    BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    AnnotatedType<T> type = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(object.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<T> it = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(type);
    CreationalContext ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
    it.inject(object, ctx);
    it.postConstruct(object);
}
```

Basically, any object to that method will get injected. All the usual CDI annotations should work. Hopefully.

Comment: Ahh, I missed these replies earlier! Thanks a lot for the quick and helpful responses - both are good suggestions, and we'll have a crack at them. Will update on here with progress...

Comment: So, it seems you're right, Tom - there's no 'nice' way of doing it in one go, you either have to put your JMX bean in CDI, as you suggest above, or put you CDIed bean into JMX.

We tried the above, but it appears the BeanManager isn't bound to JNDI at the point the service starts up.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work. Incidentally, rather than accepting my answer, you should probably have posted your own describing what you did, and accepted that. We risk confusing people who come along later and read this tortuous tale.

Comment: You have my sympathies over JBoss's startup order. We wanted to use system properties loaded by SystemPropertiesService to configure some services - but of course that's a service itself, so it hasn't done its thing at the point at which many interesting services are being configured!

Comment: Ah, joy, I think we've still got that to come!

Thanks for the answering tip, have done as you suggest now. Thanks again for your help.